# How to run micro servo with ATmega 328 PU

Tags: atmega, clock, servo, atmega328p

When I use arduino board it works fine but when I try to put it on prototype breadboard it just freez and start humming.

For circuit I am using 5v regulator, duracel 9v battery, ZTT 16.0 mx resonator(for clock), and thats it. I test it with blink sketch it works find but when I tried it with servo it not working  poroperly...

Circuit look like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXFGgVN98J0&t=5m56s

[image]

Anyone know what can be a problem?

**EDIT**

When I power arduino just with 9v battery and use pin 9 from arduino board  it works so must be some problem with resonator?

Comment: You need bypass caps.

Comment: Could you explain what i need to do?

Comment: Add small 100nF capacitors as close to the Atmega as you can and some bigger 100uF capacitors somewhere in your power rail.

Comment: Schematics, please.

Comment: Please check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXFGgVN98J0 5:56 min schematics is same as in picture...